# Angular 2 `ng build` is showing "Could not start watchman" error

Tags: angular, digital-ocean, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I am using angular-cli for my project. It is working fine in my local computer. But when I tried to run my code in the server, it is showing error.

After `git pull` in the server, I tried to `npm install` it throws me these warns-

```
npm WARN prefer global http-server@0.9.0 should be installed with -g
npm WARN cannot run in wd banbeis@0.0.0 typings install (wd=/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client)
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli requires typings@'^1.3.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/typings,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.8.1
```

And then, if I `ng build` it throws me error-

```
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
Build failed.
The Broccoli Plugin: [Funnel] failed with:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'typings'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:839:18)
    at symlink (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/symlink-or-copy/index.js:60:26)
    at symlinkOrCopySync (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/symlink-or-copy/index.js:55:5)
    at /var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:58:9
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/node_modules/promise-map-series/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
    at Funnel.Plugin (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:7:31)
    at new Funnel (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:44:10)
    at Angular2App._buildInputTree (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:85:7)
    at new Angular2App (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:51:41)
    at module.exports (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/angular-cli-build.js:6:10)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/builder.js:55:19)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/builder.js:89:10)
    at new Class (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:18:12)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/tasks/build.js:15:19)
    at /var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/commands/build.js:32:24
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at /var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:331:11
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/var/www/BANBEIS/banbeis-client/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Comment: It seems that you are missing the typings-directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLI was still using the pre 1.0 typings version, but I am having the most recent version installed. So I did -

```
rm -rf typings
npm run postinstall
ng serve
```

And now it is working :D